# How to change the placeholder title of the search box

Tags: 8, search, i18n-l10n

I created a Drupal 8 website and enabled multilingual modules, so my website is in French, English and Spanish.

In the placeholder of the search box the word *Search* appear for English and is translated in Spanish to *Buscar* but in French *Search* appears.

How can I change it to *Recherche*?

Comment: Did you try to translate 'Search' in /admin/config/regional/translate?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 8 and i can't find any /admin/ folder

Comment: You have to login as admin.